# Work around annoying code appended to my homepage by free hosting service?

Tags: javascript, html

So the bottom part of my homepage source code looks like this (simplified):

```
</body>
  </noscript>
  <div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // ads code goes here
  </script>
  </div>
</html>
```

[Detailed code here](https://gist.github.com/Abuda/57d56d2d499725bf60f18f86ab075ec1#file-ads_code-html)

I've tried using jQuery to add a `<noscript>` tag before the mentioned `<div>` after the document loads, but it didn't work.

Is there a way I can spare my visitors the trouble of dealing with that popup (other than switching host)?

Comment: In short, nope. It's likely part of the host's ToS that they have the right to stick their ads on your content, and trying to break out of that could become a thing. It's probably being done before the page even leaves the server, which kills the using jQuery workaround you have here.

Comment: Circumventing something that is no doubt compulsory within your ToS is not a good idea.

Comment: As a side note, I hope the simplieifed source code you added above is not how your host is rendering the page. As it stands, it's semantically invalid...

Comment: Well this ToS thing came across my mind for a brief second only, now I'm sure of it.  Thanks for the good news, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, insert this before their script runs:

```
<script>
    window.stop();
</script>
```

This will prevent dom onload handlers from being called, though. Among other things.

Answer (score 0):

The script from popcash.net creates a function called jsPopunder. You could try overwriting it with:

`window.jsPopunder = undefined;`